# SetTimeout в рекурсивной функции

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, settimeout

Есть код:

```js
/*Присваиваем метки*/
let label = 0;

function setLabel(y, x) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    matrix[y][x].label = label;
    setDivLabel(y, x, label);
    console.log(matrix[y][x].label);
    label = label + 1;
    if (validCell(y - 1, x) && checkCell(matrix[y - 1][x])) {
      setLabel(y - 1, x);
    }
    if (validCell(y + 1, x) && checkCell(matrix[y + 1][x])) {
      setLabel(y + 1, x);
    }
    if (validCell(y, x - 1) && checkCell(matrix[y][x - 1])) {
      setLabel(y, x - 1);
    }
    if (validCell(y, x + 1) && checkCell(matrix[y][x + 1])) {
      setLabel(y, x + 1);
    }
    label = label - 1;
  }, 500);
}

setLabel(io.enter[0], io.enter[1]);
```

При его выполнении label на каждой итерации 0. Почему так, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: `else if`? ....

Comment: Если поставлю else if, то дойдя до стенки, я не вернусь обратно. 82.179.51.71 - адрес сервера, это мой курсовой. Данный код - это реализация алгоритма трассировки поиска пути (aTrace.js).

Comment: @Igor, возможно :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в асинхронности функции `setLabel`.

Конкретно проблема в строке

```
label = label - 1;
```

Которая выполняется **до** того, как начнут выполняться функции `setLabel` внутри условий.

Из-за этого, после выхода из функции и перехода к следующим значение `label` не меняется.

Решить можно попробовать, сохраняя `label` в локальную переменную **перед** вызовом `setTimeout`

Либо передавать текущее значение `label` в качестве параметра, а не используя глобальную переменную.

Comment: Благодарю, передал в качестве параметра. Всё заработало.